# WPF listbox template horizontal with line break

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatemplate

In my WPF document i have something like:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbNames" Height="400" Width="400">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Element[Icon].Value}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Element[Name].Value}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

But I want this list horizontal and if there is not enough space, I want the next item in a new line. 
At the end it should look like a grid.

Optional: If there is not enough space vertically, I want a scrollbar.

Comment: Why dont you use a 'wrapPanel' instead of 'stackpanel'

Answer (score 3):

You need change items panel to WrapPanel

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbNames" Height="400" Width="400" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <WrapPanel/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Element[Icon].Value}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Element[Name].Value}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: What about orientation?

Answer (score -1):

What you are describing is a `WrapPanel`. This element will place your TextBlock's in a Grid format, and if they exceed the width of the WrapPanel, then the next element will be forced onto a new line.

See [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFWrapPanel.aspx) tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

To make list horizontal, use

```
Orientation="Horizontal"
```

in stackpanel. And for vertical scrollbar if it goes higher than it should, use

```
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible".
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to use wrappanel

Comment: "if there is not enough space, I want the next item in a new line"

Comment: I don't really see reason to underscore this if my answer had useful information regardin scrollbar and orientation. Even if it didn't answer fully to answer...